# Lat long variable extraction issues

Tags: javascript

i am attempting to extract a lat and long as a variable from a geocoder in order to use it in a routing parameter. I am having issues retrieving the lat long from within the function, i am sure this is something straight forward but i'm relatively new to JS with my only previous coding experience being 6 months of Python.

As shown in the code below i can print the lat long to console with this code "console.log(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition);"
but just cannot extract the lat long separately so that i may move on with the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function loadMap() {
var platform = new H.service.Platform(
    {'id': JSid ,
     'apikey': JSapikey
    });

// Retrieve the target element for the map:
var targetElement = document.getElementById('mapContainer');

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), 
                    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
                    {
                        zoom: 10,
                        center: { lat: 53.546, lng: -113.5 }
                    });

var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

var geocodingParams = {
      searchText: '10 downing street, westminster'
    }
var onResult2 = function(result) {
      console.log(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition);
    }
var onError2 = function(error) {
       console.log(error);
    };

geocoder.geocode(geocodingParams, onResult2, onError2);



var startCoords = 'geo!53.478176,-113.642455'
var endCoords = 'geo!51.1784,-115.57'

var routingParameters = {
  // The routing mode:
    'mode': 'fastest;car',
  // The start point of the route:
    'waypoint0': startCoords,
  // The end point of the route:
    'waypoint1': endCoords,
  // To retrieve the shape of the route we choose the route
  // representation mode 'display'
    'representation': 'display',

    'routeattributes' : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
    'maneuverattributes': 'direction,action',
};

var onResult = function(result) {
  var route,
  routeShape,
  startPoint,
  endPoint,
  linestring;
  if(result.response.route) {
  // Pick the first route from the response:
  route = result.response.route[0];
  // Pick the route's shape:
  routeShape = route.shape;

  // Create a linestring to use as a point source for the route line
  linestring = new H.geo.LineString();

  // Push all the points in the shape into the linestring:
  routeShape.forEach(function(point) {
  var parts = point.split(',');
  linestring.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);
  });

  // Retrieve the mapped positions of the requested waypoints:
  startPoint = route.waypoint[0].mappedPosition;
  endPoint = route.waypoint[1].mappedPosition;

  // Create a polyline to display the route:
  var routeLine = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
  style: { strokeColor: 'blue', lineWidth: 3 }
  });

  // Create a marker for the start point:
  var startMarker = new H.map.Marker({
  lat: startPoint.latitude,
  lng: startPoint.longitude
  });

  // Create a marker for the end point:
  var endMarker = new H.map.Marker({
  lat: endPoint.latitude,
  lng: endPoint.longitude
  });

  // Add the route polyline and the two markers to the map:
  map.addObjects([routeLine, startMarker, endMarker]);

  // Set the map's viewport to make the whole route visible:
  map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({bounds: routeLine.getBoundingBox()});
  }
};

var router = platform.getRoutingService();

router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, onResult,
  function(error) {
  alert(error.message);
  });

}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('DOM is ready');
  loadMap();
});
```

Comment: Please try to minimize the amount of code that is unrelated to the problem. And provide a clear indication of what you mean by "cannot extract the lat long separately". From what? What happens?

Comment: It will be worth including some documentation for the [`H.service.platform()`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.service.Platform.html) class. I had to go hunt it down to get a grasp of the codebase you are trying to implement. I still haven't gotten to the bottom of it but at least I found out what API you are using.

Comment: Can you confirm that your response from the `geocode()` method looks something like [this](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-geocode.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out what type the variable is that is logged in the console:

`console.log(typeof(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition));`

Or try JSON.stringify to find out more

`console.log(JSON.stringify(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.DisplayPosition));`